# How to add multi-level partition in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveddl

I have customer managed table in the hive, partition based on date and customerName. My directory structure is like below:

```
 user/hive/warehouse/test.db/customer/date1=2021-09-16/customerName=xyz
```

when I am doing **show partitions customer**  it is not giving output. So I tried to add a partition with

```
MSCK REPAIR TABLE customer;
```

**It give error Execution Error,return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask**

```
ALTER TABLE customer ADD PARTITION (date1='2021-09-15') PARTITION (customerName='xyz');
```

It also give error **ValidationFailureSemanticException partition spec {customername=xyz} contain non partition column**

How can I add these partitions in hive metastore.

```
hive> show create table customer;
 OK
CREATE TABLE `customer`(
`act` string)
 PARTITIONED BY (
   `date1` string,
   `customername` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'path'='hdfs://hdcluster/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/customer')
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://hdcluster/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/customer'
TBLPROPERTIES (
 'spark.sql.create.version'='2.4.0',
 'spark.sql.partitionProvider'='catalog',
 'spark.sql.sources.provider'='orc',
 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols'='2',
 'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1',
 'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'=
  '{\"type\":\"struct\",\"fields\": 
  [{\"name\":\"act\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\": 
  {}},           {\"name\":\"date1\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\":{}}, 
{\"name\":\"customername\",\"type\":\"string\",\"nullable\":true,\"metadata\ 
  ":{}}]}','spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0'='date1',
      'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.1'='customername',
      'transient_lastDdlTime'='1631781225')
```

Comment: Did you try `ALTER TABLE customer ADD PARTITION (date1='2021-09-15', customerName='xyz');
`

Comment: yes. Facing the same error.

Comment: show table DDL please

Comment: @leftjoin I am new to the hive, could you please tell me which command should I fire on hive-shell?

Comment: `describe formatted customer`  OR  `show create table customer`

Comment: @leftjoin output is attached in question

Comment: create table looks good. All should work, except your ALTER TABLE, which is wrong one. What can it be is probably partition  directory is in camelCase instead of lowercase, not sure is it an issue or not.

Comment: @leftjoin camelCase is not an issue. I tried both ways but getting the same error.

Comment: @vishwajeetMane you renamed all directories to lowercase?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE customer 
ADD PARTITION (date1='2021-09-15',customerName='xyz')
LOCATION 
    'hdfs://hdcluster/user/hive/warehouse/test.db/customer/date1=2021-09-15/customerName=xyz';
```